# When I need to create a schedule for Snapshot Agent for push transactional replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

I am working with transactional database replication for push subscriber. My database structure will not be changed soon. Do I have to use "Schedule the Snapshot Agent"?

What is the main reason to enable "Schedule the Snapshot Agent" option in snapshot agent in MSSQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subscriber gets badly out of date, it will need a snapshot to reinitialize the replication. So... if your Snapshot Agent isn't running, the system will need to store all the logs since the last snapshot, or else be unable to reinitialize a subscriber if required.

So it's best to let the Snapshot Agent run occasionally, just like it's nice to have a Full Database Backup handy for DR. Log shipping will always just use log backups, but if your log shipping has a disaster, you'll need to use a full backup to get it reinitialized.